# Outlook 2013 Search Folder from/to/cc a specific domain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, office365

I'd like to create a search folder which retrieves all mail sent from or to a specific domain (i.e. a particular vendor where I deal with multiple people). The Advanced tab in the Search Folder Criteria box appears to allow you specify words as part of a from/to/cc/bcc address, but it doesn't work if specify From contains @myvendor.com.

Screenshot: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4x5SBXWsINqYmQwclBIalhHTnM&usp=sharing)

The only workaround I can find is to use the "Search for the word(s)" @myvendor.com in "frequently-used text fields" on the Messages tab.

Thank you!

Comment: Almost there. Remove the "@" and it should work.

Comment: In outlook 2010 it works fine with @

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. It's not working for me, with or without the @.